# Do .NET Winforms controls use MSCOMCTL.OCX?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am (finally!) in the process of converting our VB6 applications to .NET (C#). I would like to use Winforms (I hope to quickly switch to MVC and make them web applications after that). We recently had some serious bizarre problems with our VB6 application on Server 2012 that I suspect may have been caused by MSCOMCTL.OCX (actually that prompted the rewrite). The more I learned about this OCX, the more I wanted to stay away from it. I'm not sure how to find out whether or not the .NET Winforms framework uses these old ActiveX components. I'm hoping someone knows or could point me in a direction to find out. I want to avoid the messy learning curve of WPF.

Comment: They do not, by default (although it *is* possible to use ActiveX controls if you need to).

Comment: This does not answer your question, and is only my opinion, but... If it were me, I'd go ahead and move the functionality to a MVC WebAPI service (or even better would be Self hosted WCF), then it won't matter what front end you point at it. It can be WinForms, WPF, web, or any combination.

Comment: So would I Kevin but it's not my call =(. Thanks Matthew.

Comment: `I want to avoid the messy learning curve of WPF` - There's no such thing. WPF is smooth and workable, while winforms is deprecated, too limited and requires too much code for anything. I'm not sure why anyone would want to write any new winforms application in 2016. Winforms code is not portable, winforms GUIs are by definition tied to the winforms APIs, while WPF supports MVVM which means you can largely reuse your GUI logic pretty much anywhere.

Comment: It is a VB6 wrapper for the common controls (ListView, TreeView, ProgressBar, etc).  A .NET program doesn't need a wrapper like that with [DllImport] readily available to directly execute unmanaged code and an object model that strongly supports editing properties at design-time..  Time has not been kind to mscomctl.ocx, it has been subjected to several security fixes that compromised compatibility, probably the underlying problem you've been having.

Comment: HighCore - I guess it's what you're used to. I got frustrated with the avalanche of markup tags and there being so many layers upon layers of templates and definitions. I plan to use the MVVM pattern in my Winforms code so I can port the logic into MVC soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The OCX extension indicates an ActiveX control. They are indeed used by the classic COM-based VB system (the latest, greatest version of which is VB 6), but they are not used by the .NET Framework. WinForms provides its own unrelated implementation of the common controls. So instead, you'll have a whole new set of bugs to contend with!

Do note that [you *can* use ActiveX controls with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984238(VS.71).aspx), and this may well be what you end up inadvertently doing if you try to convert the VB 6 project to a .NET project using some automated conversion wizard. I'm not sure, it would depend on the quality of your wizard. Generally, there would be no reason to ever use MSCOMCTL.OCX, since all of the common controls are provided by WinForms, but if your app depends on other ActiveX controls that have no equivalent, a conversion wizard would very likely try and reuse them.

(I don't know what problem you had with MSCOMCTL.OCX on Server 2012. There should not be any significant issues. VB 6 apps continue to run just fine on newer versions of Windows. Make sure that you're running the latest version of the file from the [cumulative update rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957924). A massive rewrite for a simple bug seems like overkill to me.)

Comment: MSCOMCTL.OCX has been riddled with security issues and has many KillBits (registry entries that either force an ocx control to not be loaded or 'suggest' another guid for a newer control). If you have different versions of the ocx referenced in your program (for some reason there are references to ocx's in your vb6 forms) it will actually load 2 instances of some dependent dlls into your applications memory. Note that you cannot turn off the ocx update in this instance. Visual Studio just ignores the setting, which makes it very hard to keep all your files using the same version of the OCX.

Comment: The 'bug' was that, at random intervals - hours or days - suddenly our vb6 application names were actually going 'blank' in the task manager. This actually caused some api calls to crash (Process32Next). At the same time our connections to our access databases became corrupted (for all users on the RDP!). We scanned for viruses dozens of times, created whole new server installs but nothing worked until I went through and changed every single vbp and frm file reference to MSCOMCTL.OCX to 2.0 and recompiled the application. The problem has not happened for weeks.

Comment: This 'smelled' to me like a memory corruption issue combined with some kind of shared resource working together to make a real mess.